# ElasticSearch - Throughput gradually decreases from 100k to 20k

Tags: elasticsearch

I've 2 billion documents to be indexed and once that is done, I've to do continuous stream of updates(upserts) of 40k documents per second.

Below is my cluster details:

- 15 ec2 c3.4x large boxes.
- ES Version: "2.0.2"
- 15 shards, 1 replica.

I've a fixed schema (around 10 fields with 1 field as array of integers)
`_all` is disabled. I can't use auto generated id. I defined my own id for the doc.

Below are few settings:

```
threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 3000

indices.cache.query.size: 10%

index.index_concurrency: 50

index.refresh_interval: 600s

index.translog.flush_threshold_ops: 50000

indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 30%

indices.fielddata.cache.size: 40%

indices.cluster.send_refresh_mapping: false

indices.store.throttle.max_bytes_per_sec" : 100mb
```

The cluster starts off well with 120k writes per second. But once 2 billion documents are loaded, it comes down to 20k.

I tried with 15 shards, 30 shards : both result in same results.

How can I achieve atleast 40k per second updates (upsert operations)?